# Console Line showing when doing an execlp call

Tags: c, compilation

I'm doing a program that creates 3 childs and calls 3 other programs to execute certain actions, the program works but when it prints, it prints weirdly showing alumno@DebianNSystem:~/Escritorio/Tarea1$ like in the picture, I would like some help in how to make that line not appear.
Here es the code:

int main(){

```
int i;
const char *a[3];
a[0] = "./ContadorScripts";
a[1] = "./ContadorImagenes";
a[2] = "./ContadorLinks";
printf("\n**** ESTADÍSTICAS DEL SITIO WEB ANALIZADO ****");
// create 3 child processes
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    if (fork() == 0) {
        int funcion= execlp(a[i],a[i],NULL);
        printf("PID: %d", getpid());
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

[Here is the line I don't want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3MKU.png)

Comment: That's the normal shell prompt. You get it because your main process exits, making the shell the foreground process and it displays the prompt. Just as when you run any other program. What the child-processes prints after that will be shown after the prompt.

Comment: There is any what to make that not appear? or at least make the parent print the printf("\n**** ESTADÍSTICAS DEL SITIO WEB ANALIZADO ****"); after that line? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps make the parent process **`wait`** for all its child processes to exit first?